# mongod not picking up db / collections from mongodump

Tags: mongodb

I took a mongodump like so (it worked):

```
time_millis=$(node -e 'console.log(Date.now())');

cd $HOME && mkdir -p "mongodump_dev/${time_millis}" \
&& mongodump --host "our-host" --port 12345 \
--username "admin" --password "xyz" \
--out "$HOME/mongodump_dev/${time_millis}" --db cdt_db  --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I get a directory structure that looks like this:

```
cd "$HOME/mongodump_dev/${time_millis}" && ls -a  

.                                       WiredTiger.turtle                       cdt_db                                  index-1-110924868143086153.wt           mongod.lock
..                                      WiredTiger.wt                           collection-0-110924868143086153.wt      index-3-110924868143086153.wt           sizeStorer.wt
WiredTiger                              WiredTigerLAS.wt                        collection-2-110924868143086153.wt      index-4-110924868143086153.wt           storage.bson
WiredTiger.lock                         _mdb_catalog.wt                         diagnostic.data                         journal
```

then I start mongod against this directory:

```
mongod --dbpath "$HOME/mongodump_dev/1506468317809"
```

mongod starts up successfully and the directory path is valid (otherwise mongod would conk out) but mongod doesn't pick up any of the data in that dir, the only dbs that I see are:

```
> show dbs
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the dump location is just a dump and is not same as the data in the `--dbpath` location. `mongodump` utility lets you backup your data by dumping data in a folder. You cannot use the dump location as the data folder for `mongod`. You need to first run `mongod` instance with a clean `--dbpath` folder and then load the dumped data on this running mongod instance using `mongorestore` utility.

Comment: ughhh yeah thanks, I tried mongorestore and that didn't work either, I am going to try again tomorrow.